# I have to split currency symbol ( coming from angular currency pipe ) and value into two different span, so that i can achieve the design requirements

Tags: angular

I have written custom angular pipe,  i have to transform value of another pipe into new value containing HTML div/span element? I used assigning output to innerHTML, but i still get data with additional message " **SafeValue must use [property]=binding:** ". Is this issue with implementing PIPE for generating html tags output string.

I have existing component that uses currency pipe, i have to split currency symbol and value into two different span, so that i achieve the design requirements, and this is conditional for certain case and i rely on @Input() variable

I have to rely on the result of angular currency pipe available at view html file, to add some spice to problem, the currency pipe is again coming from translate pipe for language change. 
i had worked on approach using slice pipe to separate currency symbol with 0 value and amount value in another slice, but the problem is for certain language, like french the euro symbol appears at right side, while for english it appears at left, this situation is affecting my splitting process of just currency symbol, and value

Comment: Pipes transform data into data. To visualize data with HTML formatting, you use a component, not a pipe.

Comment: Hi @JB Nizwet thanks for response,
i have existing component that uses currency pipe, i have to split currency symbol and value into two different span, so that i achieve the design requirements. I cannot do it at component level, as it is used across application.

Comment: Why couldn't you do it at component level? A component is a reusable piece of code that allows visualizing data. So create a SplitCurrencyComponent, and use it in all the templates that need to display a currency that way, passing the value to display as input.

Comment: Hey @JBNizet thanks for suggestion,
I have to rely on the result of  angular currency pipe available at view html file, I will check if i can get that data within component.

Comment: What the currency pipe does is simply calling this function: https://angular.io/api/common/formatCurrency. You can use it wherever you want. Although I don't really see ho it's relevant since apparently you want the result to be split into spans somehow. So you probably should format a number in one span, and display a currency code/symbol in the other.

Comment: Yes @JBNizet i too had worked on similar approach using slice pipe, but the problem is for certain language, like french the euro symbol appears at right side, while for english it appears at left, this situation is affecting my splitting process of just currency symbol, and value

Comment: But that is irrelevant to your question. If you don't know how to split/display a currency using a component, using a pipe instead won't magically give you the solution. If you want help on how to display something in a certain way, then ask about that, explain your requirements clearly, and post the code you tried.